# Using system_profiler with English output on German macOS

Tags: macos, font, language, system-profiler

For a macOS software that works with fonts on the bash shell I need information about the installed fonts.
To get the font information I use

```
system_profiler SPFontsDataType
```

This works fine on an English macOS.
However when run on a German macOS it outputs everything in English, except the font style.
And for compatibility I also need the font style in English.

Example German macOS:

```
Full Name: Times New Roman Fett
Family: Times New Roman
Style: Fett
```

Example English macOS:

```
Full Name: Times New Roman Bold
Family: Times New Roman
Style: Bold
```

I tried to set to change AppleLanguages in the defaults for system_profiler, but it didn't work. The output was still in German:

```
defaults write com.apple.systemprofiler AppleLanguages '("en-US","de-DE")'

defaults write com.apple.systemprofiler AppleLanguages -array "en-US" "de-DE"
```

However when I temporarily set the NSGlobalDomain to English it worked:

```
tempvalues=$(defaults read NSGlobalDomain AppleLanguages)
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleLanguages -array "en-US" 
system_profiler SPFontsDataType
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleLanguages "$tempvalues"
```

But isn't there a better approach than changing the NSGlobalDomain?
Calling system_profiler takes a few seconds, so it might affect other programs too.

From the fonts I need:
the full name, family, style, file name and location (=full path), version, copy protected field, embeddable field.
All this info is available in SPFontsDataType.

Comment: It would be useful if you would list the information you're trying to obtain (and even why the app needs it).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest it's much easier to use [NSFontManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfontmanager) than trying to use the localised information from System Profiler.

Here's a Swift script that produces a list of the PostScript names of every installed font.

```
#!/usr/bin/swift    
import AppKit
    
    let manager = NSFontManager.shared
    let fontList = manager.availableFonts
    
    print (fontList)
```

If you just want to check whether a particular font is installed, then there are easy ways of doing that.

However, this is straying into software development, which is off-topic here, and for which [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) is more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, but as far as I know NSFontManager doesn't return all necessary font info. For example the file name or the font version string is not available. That's why we use SPFontsDataType.

Comment: @mart5 This is why it's important to explain what you're trying to achieve, rather than what you're doing. Ask "I need to get the following information".

Comment: I read this entry before posting the question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159064/
That's why I landed here and not in Stack Overflow. 
And I had hoped there was a similar simple solution.